# Loop over a list of data frames to generate heatmaps and save them

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames called tagMatrixList from the package ChIPseeker. Is there a way to generate tagHeatmap (tagMatrixList, xlim=c(-3000, 3000), color="blue") for each data frame and then save each single plot in a file?

```
      List of 41
      $ : int [1:11715, 1:6001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
        ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
        .. ..$ : chr [1:11715] "5" "7" "8" "10" ...
        .. ..$ : NULL
       $ : int [1:9414, 1:6001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
        ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
        .. ..$ : chr [1:9414] "4" "5" "7" "10" ...
        .. ..$ : NULL
       $ : int [1:10498, 1:6001] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
        ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
        .. ..$ : chr [1:10498] "4" "6" "7" "9" ...
        .. ..$ : NULL
       $ : int [1:6849, 1:6001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
        ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
        .. ..$ : chr [1:6849] "5" "6" "10" "12" ...
        .. ..$ : NULL
       $ : int [1:10823, 1:6001] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
        ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
        .. ..$ : chr [1:10823] "6" "7" "9" "12" ...
```

I tried:

```
    plots = lapply(tagMatrixList, function(x)  tagHeatmap(tagMatrix, xlim=c(-3000, 3000),color="blue")) but the output is:                    
                   List of 41
                  $ : NULL             
                  $ : NULL       
                  $ : NULL        
                  $ : NULL
```

So I cannot save the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open up a image device to save the plot to it (such as png(), pdf(), etc.), and then close it with dev.off() when you're done.

Since your list doesn't have names and you want a file for each plot, we'll loop over a vector of numbers instead to both index the object, and add a file name with that index number.

```
lapply(seq_len(length(tagMatrixList)), function(x) {
  p <- tagHeatmap(tagMatrixList[x], xlim=c(-3000, 3000),color="blue")
  png(paste0("heatmap_", x, ".png"), height = 5, width = 5)
  p; dev.off()
})
```

The tidyverse package purrr has a nice convenience function for this too, called iwalk.

```
purrr::iwalk(tagMatrixList, function(x, y) {
  p <- tagHeatmap(x, xlim=c(-3000, 3000),color="blue")
  png(paste0("heatmap_", y, ".png"), height = 5, width = 5)
  p; dev.off()
})
```